# grails, drools, and ticket / issue trackers, iTicket

Tags: grails, drools

I need to integrate a ticketing system into my grails Web application, so that those running the small company can easily handle customer needs / complaints, etc., tying that in directly with their users. When I searched for a plugin or built application, I found:

- [drools plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/drools), small ticketing capability/example, which after having an installation bug led me to
- [drools-gorm plugin](http://www.grails.org/Drools+Plugin), and then also briefly reviewing
- [iTicket](http://groovysource.com/open-source/issue-trackers/i-ticket), which I'm just currently shying away from because of its inclusion of roles management but no mention of Spring Security Core and UI, which is what I'm using for role management
- [article on building a small issue tracker with Grails](http://josh-in-antarctica.blogspot.com/2008/04/writing-simple-issue-tracker-in-grails.html)

I don't have a lot of problem domain knowledge with ticketing systems, and so I'm wondering if someone whose gone down this road before or knows ticketing system domain modelling & rules engines in general can give a few comments.  E.g. are flexible rules engines very important for ticketing systems, or is this only for heavier weight applications?  What kinds of other general things can one do with grails plus drools, that might be useful?  Alternatively, the opposite, is staying light weight best, because these things often turn out to be very "custom" in this arena.

Your experience is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The need for flexibility isn't predicated on system weight, but on needs. Do you need custom issue workflows? Do they need to be integrated on-the-fly? Are there complex needs for who, where, when, and how issues may be entered? Drools is a general-purpose rules engine-the scope of its capabilities go beyond a general SO question; the documentation and examples are a better source of information for  its general capabilities. I know, -1.

Comment: Dave, thanks for your "requirement questions".  I didn't get your last sentence, however.